# when Task.IsCancelled is set as true?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

when will come **Task.IsCanceled = true;**

Code:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
string result = "";
cts.CancelAfter(10000);
try
{
    Task t = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var stream = new WebClient().OpenRead("http://www.rediffmail.com"))
        {
            result = "success!";
        }
        cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }, cts.Token);
    
    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();
    while (timer.IsRunning)
    {
        if (timer.ElapsedMilliseconds <= 10000)
        {
            if (result != ""){                                                                                      
                timer.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Stop();
            //cts.Cancel();
            //cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
    }
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.IsCanceled); // still its appear in false.
}
```

My requirement is - Task is not completed upto 10seconds, Need to cancel the task.

So I am setting timer and watch upto the given seconds. its not completed mean cancel the task and showing error message.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What you have shown is incomplete.

Comment: Cancelling the token isn't enough, you need to check the `method` code for cancelling the job

Comment: Can you show the code where the Task t is awaited? And to be correct, you want to cancel the whole operation if the method takes longer than 20 seconds to run, do you?

Comment: Where will i share the code. Here not able to share the code. showing Too long

Answer (score 4):

From documentation:

> A Task will complete in the TaskStatus.Canceled state under any of the following conditions:
>
> 1. Its CancellationToken was marked for cancellation before the task started executing.
> 2. The task acknowledged the cancellation request on its already signaled CancellationToken by throwing an OperationCanceledException that bears the same CancellationToken.
> 3. The task acknowledged the cancellation request on its already signaled CancellationToken by calling the ThrowIfCancellationRequested method on the CancellationToken.

So basically you would need to throw an `OperationCanceledException` within your task to force the state for instance by executing `cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` just after you cancel it.

But the intention of this mechanism is a bit the other way around. You cancel source say while user presses cancel button on your form (from outside of your task) an task just verifies if cancellation was requested in some safe to cancel points of its code.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the token to your method. It should inspect the token and respect the call to `Cancel()` of the `CancellationTokenSource`.

Or you do it yourself:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    myResult = method();  // Request processing in parallel

    cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // React on cancellation 
}, cts.Token);
```

A complete example is this:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var ct = cts.Token;
    cts.CancelAfter(500);

    Task t = null;
    try
    {
        t = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); }, ct);
        await t;
        Console.WriteLine(t.IsCanceled);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.IsCanceled);
    }
}
```

The output is that an `OperationCanceledException` is thrown and the result is

> True

if you remove the `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` part it will show

> False

**Edit:**

Now, you have updated the question, some comments on that. First, you won't need the timer anymore since you are using the `CancelAfter` method. Second, you need to `await` your task. So that makes something like this:

```
string result = "";
cts.CancelAfter(10000);
Task t = null;
try
{
    t = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var stream = new WebClient().OpenRead("http://www.rediffmail.com"))
        {
            cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            result = "success!";
        }
    }, cts.Token);

    await t;
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.IsCanceled); 
}
```

This should show that `t.IsCanceled` is `true` but of course only when the call of the `WebClient` takes longer that 10 seconds.

Comment: Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    myResult = method();  // Request processing in parallel
}, cts.Token);
// After some time
cts.cancel
 cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); 

IS it possible or not? here t.iscancelled never comes with true.

Comment: Can you show the code where the Task t is awaited? And to be correct, you want to cancel the whole operation if the method takes longer than 20 seconds to run, do you?

Comment: How to share the code? here comes up with too long characters.

Comment: Edit or add it to your question, that is the best way.

Comment: its not working. Web client takes 10seconds. but still its not coming for catch operation.After getting results only result will be returned because of await opeation. Without await its possible?

Comment: Can you then put you zipped code somewhere on dropbox / onedrive or whatever so I can take a look?

Comment: yes. I created sample for this issue and uploaded in we transfer. Please check below link: 
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8b1531c554fc96490773c1a72692b5a620170214060030/4473cf

Please help me for this issue.

Comment: In your code, the line `using (var stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.yahoo.com"))` of course does not take 3 or more seconds so it won't be cancelled. I have added a `Thread.Sleep(5000)` to simulate a call that should be canceled and that just works. See my updated version at https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/481523d78781e769b610fda74960a8f220170214190937/a7dd445aa413e11d6d433789e265c84c20170214190937/a9aef3

Comment: Oh one more very important thing: Yes, if the web client takes 10 seconds than it will *not* abort after 3 seconds. That is because the  `OpenRead` method does not support cancellation so it cannot be aborted!